# How to trigger a memory warning

Tags: xcode

What's the easiest way to trigger a memory warning?

Comment: Did you try Hardware/Simulate Memory Warning from the simulator's menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:                     
    @"UIApplicationMemoryWarningNotification" object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Comment: use UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification

Answer (score 7):

In the Simulator you can go under "Hardware" and select "Simulate Memory Warning".

[image]

If you are trying to do this on a real iOS device, [this blog post](http://www.bdunagan.com/2008/10/01/triggering-didreceivememorywarning-on-the-iphone/) explains how to send a memory warning in code.

Answer (score 1):

I like to put something hidden in my app in debug mode, such as a triple click on a certain area of my UI that triggers this:

```
- (void) simulateMemoryWarning:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TriggerManualMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
```

}

Then in my app delegate:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceiveManualMemoryWarning:) name:TriggerManualMemoryWarningNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
- (void) didReceiveManualMemoryWarning:(NSNotification *)notification {
 #ifdef DEBUG
    SEL memoryWarningSel = @selector(_performMemoryWarning);
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:memoryWarningSel]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:memoryWarningSel];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"Whoops UIApplication no loger responds to -_performMemoryWarning");
    }
  #else
    NSLog(@"%@",@"Warning: performFakeMemoryWarning called on a non debug build");
  #endif
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I added notification to shake gesture and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

In the simulator, you can simulate one...

From the device, you may want to allocate huge amounts of memory (through `malloc`, for instance).
You'll need to do it by steps, otherwise the application may just crash without the memory warning.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(Notification(name: UIApplication.didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, object: UIApplication.shared, userInfo: nil))
```

Observer

```
let cancellable = NotificationCenter.default
    .publisher(for: UIApplication.didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification)
    .sink { _ in
        print("Received memory warning")
    }
```

I found it useful in tests.